# How can I change multiple CSS elements property at once and loop infinitely?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make it where all the boxes change color whenever I click on the button and make it run continuously until I click the button again to stop it.

I tried querySelectorAll() but it only changes the first box's color

Here is my codepen showing what is happening
https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/bGEowbO

Here is the javascript below

```
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-1')
const boxes = document.querySelector('.box')


function getRandomColor() {
  let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

colorBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let newColors = getRandomColor()
  boxes.style.background = newColors
})
```

Edit: I fixed it by adding a forEach()

```
colorBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  boxes.forEach(color => {
let newColors = getRandomColor()
    color.style.background = newColors
  })
})
```

Comment: If you'd like the colours to fade into their replacements, add `transition: all 0.4s` to the CSS rule for `.box`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all classes with `box`

Then you will do forEach loop and also call that `getRandomColor` function as well to get diffrent colors applied individually.

You can read more about looping with `querySelectorAll` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/) and explained in details

Run snippet below to see it all working.

```js
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-1')
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
var running = false

function getRandomColor() {
  let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function start() {
  if (running) {
    boxes.forEach(color => {
      let newColors = getRandomColor()
      color.style.background = newColors
    })
    setTimeout(start, 500)
  }
}

colorBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  colorBtn.innerText = 'Stop'
  if (running) {
    running = false
    colorBtn.innerText = 'Change Color'
  } else {
    running = true
    start()
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(51, 51, 51, 1) 0%, rgba(29, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.btn-container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  background: linear-gradient(13deg, rgba(34, 81, 249, 1) 0%, rgba(19, 246, 255, 1) 100%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  background: blue;
  padding: 3rem 3rem;
}

#box-1 {
  background: white;
}

#box-2 {
  background: red;
}

#box-3 {
  background: green;
}

#box-4 {
  background: yellow;
}

#box-5 {
  background: orange;
}

#box-6 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box" id="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box-3"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box-4"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box-5"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn" id="btn-1">Change Color</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah that's weird that mine wasn't working then. Is it because I tried to save `let newColors = getRandomColor()`? Is that not the proper way to save a function or am I not supposed to rename functions to variables?

Comment: ah nvm I had it outside of the forEach function so my scope was off. Simply mistake but i figured it out

Comment: @Brian yes its because you were not the `getRandomColor()` in a `forEach` as well. When you clicked once the return will be applied to all divs with class box because it getRandomColor() was called only once.

Comment: @Brian Glad to hear that. Do not forget to accept as the answer if i helped you out :) Thanks

Comment: @Brian Let me update my answer to what you want - no worries. with start and stop.

Comment: I figured out how to make it loop infinitely with setTImeout, but i don't know how to make it stop. Also, I'd like to have the button text change when I click on it to say "Stop" and then when I click stop it will end the loop

Comment: @Brian I have updated my answer to what you want with start and stop option added. Cheers

Comment: Could you check my codepen and see if you could edit it to work with only one button? https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/bGEowbO

Comment: @Brian Working with one button as you wanted to be. Run Snippet  to see it. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the "All" in `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-1')
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box') 
 

function getRandomColor() {
    let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let color = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

colorBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
boxes.forEach(x=>x.style.background = getRandomColor())
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%, rgba(29,19,19,1) 100%);
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 60rem;
}

.btn-container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    background: linear-gradient(13deg, rgba(34,81,249,1) 0%, rgba(19,246,255,1) 100%);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}

.box-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
    background: blue;
    padding: 3rem 3rem; 
}

#box-1 {
    background: white;
}


#box-2 {
    background: red;
}

#box-3 {
    background: green;
}

#box-4 {
    background: yellow;
}

#box-5 {
    background: orange;
}

#box-6 {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box" id="box-1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-3"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-4"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-5"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="btn" id="btn-1">Change Color</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Also, I think you want to have different colors for each box, so I changed a bit your code.